# How can I send a chart created by google script in ChartType format over email which help users see values of various points in the graph?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart();
var range = sheet.getRange('A1:B3');
chartBuilder.addRange(range)
            .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
            .setOption('title', 'New')
var chart = chartBuilder.build();
```

Now I have to send this chart as a **ChartType** to email body not **image/png** where user could see the values of various points in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Add setOption as below:

```
.setOption("series", {
                "0": {
                    "dataLabel": "value",
                     "annotations": {
                       "textStyle": {
                          "color": "red",
                          "fontSize": 30,
                          "bold": true
                       }
                      }
                     }
           });
```

Hope this helps. :)